# Use of beta-2 microglobulin staining to assess frozen tissue sample integrity

Tags: literature

In a Russian paper I'm reading the authors use staining for beta-2 microglobulin (B2M) to make sure that a variety of frozen tissue samples still express antigens on their surface, so that these samples could be used to assess the activity of an antibody they are researching.

The authors write that "since virtually each cell expresses B2M on its surface, this assay ensures that other antigens have remained on the surface of the examined cells as well".

Is there a special term for this kind of check? Is this anti-B2M staining a routine procedure, and are there papers dedicated to this procedure? I haven't found relevant papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it is not common practice to look for B2M, although I guess there will be heavy users would would disagree.

Without seeing the paper I cannot be sure, but I guess they are using B2M as a [housekeeping gene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Housekeeping_gene), that is, a molecule whose presence and quantity is largely unregulated in living cells, and which is commonly used in labs as reference. Biological samples vary greatly in their content. It is hard to tell if a molecule is made or destroyed in response to a treatment, by merely measuring, and finding more or less of it. But if the ratio between the aforementioned molecule to an unregulated molecule goes up, you can be more sure it responded to the treatment. That is called an internal control. You may be familiar with "normalization to actin" or to GAPDH in immunoblot and qRT-PCR.

The use you are describing is diverging from the typical use of housekeeping genes in a lab, and not optimal for what they were trying to show. Since it's there in pretty much any tissue measured by immunoblot, B2M is expected to be present in any tissue assayed by microscopy. If a tissue slide lacks B2M, it is likely spoilt. But if it has B2M, it doesn't make it 100% certain that other, scarcer, more unstable molecules have been preserved as well. It would be ideal if they looked for the specific molecule they were studying; but if many of their samples were supposedly devoid of the latter, they had to replace the ideal with something more practical.

Note that I am using "molecule" in an ambiguous manner. With antigens in the referenced paper, it's obvious B2M is used as a reference protein. But housekeeping genes, including B2M, are also used as internal control for mRNA measurements ("gene expression").